# How to Specify Private Maven Repository Strategy in Jenkins Pre Steps?

Tags: maven, jenkins, repository

I have configured a "Maven Project" in Jenkins that consists of two steps:

1. Pre Step - Invoke top-level Maven targets: `mvn install <some pom.xml>`
2. Build: `mvn install <root pom.xml>`

In both steps, I selected the option "Use private Maven repository" to enforce all artifacts being installed into the $WORKSPACE/.repository directory. However, I have two problems with that:

1. In the Build step, I can select between "default", "local to the executor" and "local to the workspace", but in the Pre Step, no strategy is available! How can I chose a strategy in the Pre Step?
2. According to the info icon on the side, selecting "Use private Maven repository" in the Pre Step has the effect that "Jenkins will tell Maven to use $WORKSPACE/.repository as the local Maven repository". However, this is not at all the case! The built artifacts end up in ~/.m2, not as expected in the job's local workspace...

In the documentation of the [usePrivateRepository](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/Maven.html#usePrivateRepository) flag, the following is written:

> If true, the build will use its own local Maven repository via "-Dmaven.repo.local=...".

I'm really wondering what those `...`are and if that value can be modified. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Those `...` simply means that you should specify your _own_ custom path there. For ex., `-Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.repository`

Comment: That is exactly the problem. The Jenkins job configuration only provides a check-box, there is no apparent way to specify the maven.repo.local property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default local repo location you can always pass in the value thru `Maven Properties`. However, this is **not recommended** because then you have to add steps to cleanup the repository as well.

```
maven.repo.local=$LOCAL_REPO_PATH
```